# how get real client ip in docker?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, kong

this is my compose file:

```
version: "3.3"

networks:
  mynet:
    name: mynet

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - F:\home\config\nginx\nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - 89:89
    network_mode: host  

  api-gateway:
    image: kong:latest
    restart: always
    privileged: true
    volumes:
       - /home/log/proxy_gateways/:/home/log/
       - F:\home\kong:/home/kong
    environment:
      - KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN=127.0.0.1:8001,127.0.0.1:8446, 127.0.0.1:8444 ssl
      - KONG_PROXY_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:5000
      - KONG_LOG_LEVEL=info
      - KONG_DECLARATIVE_CONFIG=/home/kong/kong.yml
      - KONG_PLUGINS=cors,rate-limiting  
      - KONG_REAL_IP_HEADER=X-Forwarded-For
      - KONG_REAL_IP_RECURSIVE=on
    networks:
      - mynet
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
      
  myservice:
    image: myservice:3.2.1
    restart: always
    networks:
      - mynet
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
      - 88:88
```

when i try to get client ip i recieve gateway ip in my network (mynet)
indeed i run `docker network inspect` and the result is:

```
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        }
```

this is my nginx config ====================================>

```
server {
listen                      89;
server_name                 localhost;
location / {
    proxy_pass              http://192.168.139.170:5000;
    proxy_http_version      1.1;
    proxy_cache_bypass      $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    real_ip_recursive       on;
}
}
```

and whenever i want to get client ip (for every client) i get gateway ip in upside (172.18.0.1)
,how get real client ip?

Comment: What is nginx config?

Comment: @Andromeda 
    server {
 listen                      89;
 server_name                 localhost;
 location / {
     proxy_pass              http://192.168.139.170:5000;
        proxy_http_version      1.1;
        proxy_cache_bypass      $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  real_ip_recursive       on;
 }
    }

Comment: Would you please update the question with the nginx conf?

Comment: @Andromeda It was updated